# What does "his laughter usually at his own expense" mean in Chinese?

Tags: translation

What does "his laughter usually at his own expense" mean in Chinese? I use Google 翻譯, its answer is "他通常在自費的笑聲", which is very strange to me.

Note: It is my first time to ask question here. If my question is not appropriate or needs to be edited, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: google: word for word translation, which does not seem accurate, try jukuu ("laughter own expense"), one relevant example: 2.  One reason was that he had a sense of humour and could take a joke at his own expense.
 其中一个原因是他很有点幽默感，很能自我解嘲。

Comment: 自我解嘲 looks like a 成语，cf。bkrs：
zì wǒ jiě cháo
to refer to one's foibles or failings with self-deprecating humor
zì wǒ jiě cháo
用言语或行动为自己掩盖或辩解被人嘲笑的事。
zì wǒ jiě cháo
自己帮自己找理由以掩饰过错。
如：「他讪讪的自我解嘲说：『这有什么大不了的，何必发那么大的脾气。』」
自己以言语或行动来掩盖、粉饰被人嘲笑的事情。
zì wǒ jiě cháo
console oneself with soothing remarks; find excuses to console oneself; pat oneself on the back because one's feelings have been wounded (hurt); play sourgrape (sweet lemon)
console oneself with soothing remarks; find excuses to console oneself
zìwǒ jiěcháo
find excuses to console oneself in a humorous manner; be self-mocking

Comment: @user6065 Thank you for your comment. I have learned a lot. :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems to essentially be a question about understanding English from the perspective of a Chinese speaker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Original post meant, how do you translate, laughing at own expense.

An simple translation would be 笑自己 / 開(自己)玩笑